# Using IdHttp and IdConnectionIntercept created at runtime

Tags: multithreading, delphi, runtime, idhttp

I have a method that makes a connection with a RESTful server, and it uses the TIdHttp components, TIdConnectionIntercept and others created at runtime, so far so good, the problem is that I need to get the return of the event "OnReceive" the TIdConnectionIntercept component, I tried to pass a variable "out" in the event parameters, most did not work:

```
procedure ConHttpThread;
    var
     IdHTTPLibSysLoc : TIdHTTP;
     IdCookieManagerLibSysLoc : TIdCookieManager;
     IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc : TIdConnectionIntercept;
     AuthSSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
     IdLogDebug1Loc : TIdLogDebug;
     sHtmlResp, sHtmlRet, xUrlPost : String;
     paramsLog : TStringList;
   begin
    AuthSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    IdLogDebug1Loc := TIdLogDebug.Create(nil);
    IdCookieManagerLibSysLoc := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
    IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc := TIdConnectionIntercept.Create;
    IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc.Intercept := IdLogDebug1Loc;
    IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc.OnReceive := IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive;
    IdHTTPLibSysLoc := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

    try
      xUrlPost := 'url...';
      paramsLog := TStringList.Create;
      paramsLog.Add('user=' + user);
      paramsLog.Add('pass=' + xSenhaToken);

      sHtmlResp := IdHTTPLibSysLoc.Post(xUrlPost, paramsLog);
      sHtmlRet := ''; //variable s event IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive
    except
      sHtmlRet := ''; //variable s event IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive
    end;
    IdHTTPLibSysLoc.Disconnect;
   end;
```

OnReceive Event component "IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLoc"

```
procedure TFPrin.IdConnectionInterceptLibSysLocReceive(
  ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept; var ABuffer: TIdBytes);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := Low(ABuffer) to High(ABuffer) do
    s := s + UTF8Encode(chr(ABuffer[i]));
end;
```

The event is called when does TidHttp.Post (), and when the server returns an error, it goes straight to the Except, I can not use a variable glogal, the main method "ConHttpThread" is mult thread, it is called the event "ConnectionDataAvailable" component "TWSocketServer" any idea how to catch the return after the Post?

```
  { TClientConnection is used to handle client connections }
  TClientConnection = class(TWSocketClient)
  protected
      FRcvdLine : String;         { Buffer for commands              }
      FIndex    : Integer;        { Slot number as known by server   }
      ConnectTime  : TDateTime;
      procedure ConnectionDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; Error : Word);
  public
      constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  end;
```

...

```
constructor TClientConnection.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    ConnectTime       := now;
    Banner            := '';
    OnDataAvailable := ConnectionDataAvailable;
end;
```

...

```
procedure TClientConnection.ConnectionDataAvailable(
    Sender: TObject;
    Error : Word);
var
Command : String;
begin
  Command := ReceiveStr;
  ConHttpThread; //Restful connection method
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly by using an Intercept? If you are just trying to access the error data, you are going about it the wrong way. If Post()` is successful, it returns the response data to you. If it fails, the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception contains the response data.

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem.